# Postfix relayhost communication through Squid proxy?

Tags: postfix-mta, squid

I'm running postfix inside a private network and external communication can happen only through squid proxy. My relay host is AWS SES. Is there a way to make the relay host communication happen through squid proxy?

I've been looking into rinetd and `ssconnect`. I think we can do this with `ssconnect` according to this [post](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=553665)  but I can't find a package to install on ubuntu for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, hope this still can help. It is based upon [this post](https://lanbugs.de/howtos/security/ssh-uber-proxy-mit-sconnect/) translated from German.

You can find sconnect today [here](https://gist.github.com/skreuzer/1517867).

It is a small program what you can use to ssh via a proxy - specifically via a socks or HTTP proxy:

To make it runnable you can do:

```
$ gcc -o sconnect connect.c
$ cp sconnect /usr/local/bin (or your a folder where it is globally reachable) 
$ nano ~/.ssh/config
```

And then edit the ssh config like this:

```
# Usage with Socks proxy
ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/sconnect -4 -S your-socks-server:1080 %h %p

# Usage with HTTP Proxy
ProxyCommand connect /usr/local/bin/sconnect -4 -H proxy.local.net:8080 %h %p
```